# How to format JSON with Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

When I use `JsonUtility.ToJson()` from Unity (2019.3.0) it returns the JSON string in one line like:

`{"ID":0,"Name":"David","HairColor":{"r":0,"g":0,"b":0}}`

My question is: How can I make it to get:

```
{
    "ID":0,
    "Name":"David",
    "HairColor":{
        "r":0,
        "g":0,
        "b":0
    }
}
```

And can I use too `JsonUtility.FromJson()` to get the information as simple as always?

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to read [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html):

> ### `JsonUtility.ToJson`
>
> ```
> public static string ToJson(object obj, bool prettyPrint);
> ```
>
> `prettyPrint` If true, format the output for readability. If false,
>   format the output for minimum size. Default is false.

Comment: I can't believe that, I spent like 1 hour looking for this, reading every documentation I found and people questions... Thank you, I will select your answer as soon as Stackoverflow let me.

Comment: @SinfonierDominante you are welcome. Just curious though: How did you searched? What documentation did you read?

Comment: This one https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html but was totally my fault because I even read the one you said and in some way I didn't saw the prettyPrint argument. Thank you again.